# Convert string to byte array c#

Tags: c#, string, arrays

I obtained a byte array using `File.ReadAllBytes();` and I converted it into a string (`s`).

I converted my byte array to simple string using this code:

```
        string name;
        string s;
        byte[] bytes;

        bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(name);
        foreach (byte b in bytes)
        {
            s = s + b + ".";
        }
```

Now `s` is something like `"255.0.0.12.100.4.24.40.0.0.200"`. Now I want to convert this string into a file. Using `s.Split('.')` I can get all the individual numbers. But how can I copy all the bytes into a file? (reconstruct the original file)

Comment: @VolkanPaksoy: No, that's not at all what's desired here.

Comment: `File.ReadAllBytes` doesn't return a `string[]` - it returns a `byte[]`. Please give a [mcve] - at the moment your question doesn't make much sense. (It would without the last sentence - at which point I'd just suggest `array.Select(x => byte.Parse(x)).ToArray()`...)

Comment: @JonSkeet: ok, deleted it. wasn't paying much attention tbh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to convert each string into a single byte (parse the string), here's a small program that should demonstrate how to do what you're looking for:

```
void Main()
{
    string[] vals = new string[10];
    // populate vals...
    byte[] bytes = new byte[vals.Length];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (string s in vals)
    {
        bytes[i++] = byte.Parse(s);
    }
}
```

Note that there's no error handling here for the case where the string doesn't parse properly into a byte; in that situation you'll get an exception from the `byte.Parse` method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by your string array being filled with [File.ReadAllBytes()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as this returns a byte[] not a string[]. However, that aside and focusing more on your desire to have a string[] converted to a byte[] you could do something like this (assumes your string[] is called 'str'):

```
byte[] MyByteArray = str.Select(s => Byte.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```